# How to inherit and use swagger’s schema annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, swagger

I would like to inherit and use swagger’s schema annotation.
For example, a swagger document is being created in the name field within a java class as shown below.

```
@Schema(title = "birthDay", example = "2001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
private LocalDateTime birth;
```

However, since many classes also use fields similar to birth, I don't want to code `@Schema(title = "birthDay" ...` every time.

How can I create a custom annotation `@SchemaBirthDay`

I would like to write `birthDay` and `example = 2001-01-01` in the Swagger document.

Even though I created the `@SchemaBirthDay` annotation and declared `@Schema`, it is not written in the Swagger document.

My environment:

- java 17
- 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.3'
- implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.2'

Comment: You say you created a `@SchemaBirthDay` annotation, can you show the actual code?